# Same data displayed in different locations in ArcGIS Explorer and QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, file-geodatabase, arcgis-explorer

I've been working on some GIS data in middle eastern countries.
A client gave me the data in `.gdb` format. So I thought it could be loaded in QGIS.

However, when I load the data with QGIS, they are located in a totally different place (well, to be more precise, the longitude seems correct but the latitude comes around the equator).

The strange part is when I load the same data with ArcGIS Explorer, they are on the correct location. So it's not the problem with the original data, but with the way I load them.

I don't have ArcDesktop, so my destination is to be able to deal with the data on my QGIS.

I tried `ogr2ogr` conversion from `gdb to shp` but it just gives the same result, which means, when I load the resulted shapefile it goes to the wrong location.

The above trial made me think there might be special georeference method or expression which can be loaded by ESRI system but not by QGIS/GDAL, though at the moment I have no idea what it is. Any clue?

Comment: Does it come in with an already defined coordinate reference system? I would suspect that QGIS is not able to read the Esri CRS or has a different definition.

Comment: Thanks mkennedy for comment. Maybe you're right. 
The current data is from Kuwait, and the property of the original data on Arc Explorer tells its CRS is "KTM_DUC." 
When gdb is read in QGIS, its CRS is automatically recognized as "customized CRS."
Just don't know how to deal with it... Maybe should I get the detailed parameters of "KTM_DUC"?

Comment: Hmm, can you find the details of QGIS' CRS and KTM_DUC in ArcExplorer? If so, can you add the details to your question by editing it? Maybe I'll see something or can tell you how to modify the QGIS version.